# Spark with Java - Error: Cannot load main class from JAR

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-mllib, spark-submit

I am trying a simple movie recommendation machine learning program in spark. 
Spark version:2.1.1
Java version:java 8 
Scala version: Scala code runner version 2.11.7 
Env: windows 7

Running these commands to start master and worker slaves

```
//start master
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master

//start worker
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://valid ip:7077
```

I am trying a very simple movie recommendation code from here: http://blogs.quovantis.com/recommendation-engine-using-apache-spark/

I have updated code to :

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Collaborative Filtering Example").setMaster("spark://valid ip:7077");
conf.setJars(new String[] {"C:\\Spark2.1.1\\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars\\spark-mllib_2.11-2.1.1.jar"});
```

I cannot run this thru intelliJ
Running mvn clean install and copying the jar to folder does not work.
The command I used to run on :

```
bin\spark-submit --verbose –-jars jars\spark-mllib_2.11-2.1.1.jar –-class “com.abc.enterprise.RecommendationEngine” –-master spark://valid ip:7077 C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-mllib-example\spark-poc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-mllib-example\ratings.csv C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-mllib-example\movies.csv 10
```

The error I see is:

```
C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7>bin\spark-submit --verbose --class "com.sandc.enterprise.RecommendationEngine" --master spark://10.64.98.101:7077 C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-
bin-hadoop2.7\spark-mllib-example\spark-poc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-mllib-example\ratings.csv C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-m
llib-example\movies.csv 10
Using properties file: C:\Spark2.1.1\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..\conf\spark-defaults.conf
Adding default property: spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
Adding default property: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
Adding default property: spark.eventLog.enabled=true
Adding default property: spark.driver.memory=5g
Adding default property: spark.master=spark://valid ip:7077
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/C:/Spark2.1.1/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/û-class
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

If I give the --jar command, it gives the error:

```
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/C:/Spark2.1.1/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/û-jars
```

Any ideas how I can submit this job to spark??

Answer (score 0):

Is your Jar built correctly ?
Also you don't need to add double quotes for --class option value.

Comment: It has double quotes for --class option. I tried building jar like this also: mvn clean package assembly:single
But no luck.